# Can I use garam masala instead of curry powder?

Tags: curry

When I don't have curry powder can I use garam masala as a substitute? Can it give the same taste as curry powder or not? If use garam masala how much should be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add garam masala  in curry. Its taste is not like curry powder but adding in curry it gives delicious taste. I used garam masala in curry at my home. you can add 1 tble spoon of grinded garam masala in curry before adding yogurt in it.

Answer (score 11):

No, you won't get the same flavor or color. Curry powder is a blend of turmeric, cumin, coriander, and sometimes fenugreek, black pepper, mustard or cardamom. Curry powder is generally added towards the beginning of a recipe and cooked with the food.

Garam masala is a finishing spice blend shares some of the ingredients of curry powder (cumin and coriander) but is significantly different in that generally has cinnamon, bay leaves, fennel seed and cloves. Garam masala has many aromatic spices in it, and it is generally added towards the end of a recipe to give it an aromatic punch.

Comment: Especially, some garam masala recipes might completely miss out on adding any of the red chile pepper expected of a curry powder, or they might have far less turmeric. The kind of recipe where garam masala is typically used will add either of these at other points in the cooking process!

Comment: Absolutely @rackandboneman, it's common to have both.

Comment: Was thinking of classic "mustard -> cumin,bay leaf,whole spices -> onions -> green chili,ginger,garlic->turmeric,lal mirch,coriander powder, a bit garam masala -> tomatoes -> ...... -> more garam masal" workflow....